# Как сделать, чтобы элемент пропускал нажатия сквозь себя?

Tags: java, android

Нужно как-то наложить сетку поверх экрана, чтобы при этом обрабатывались нажатия по элементам, находящимся за этой сеткой. Как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: А какова функциональность сетки? В чем идея? Может достаточно сделать таким задний фон?

Comment: нужно больше информации, хотя бы изображение с дизайном.

Comment: если мой ответ помог регить проблему, отметьте его верным, поставив галочку. Это будет знаком правильности ответа для других,, кто будет искать информацию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть `FrameLayout`. Например, вот тут на переднем плане - наполовину прозрачная "пленка", а за ней `ProgressBar`

```
<FrameLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <ProgressBar
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

      <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="#85000000"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Замените `ProgressBar` на `Layout` с вашими кнопками и поставьте сетку :)

Comment: нет. элементы выстраиваются по порядку `XML`. Я сам только сделал `background` у `LinearLayout` полностью черным. Он закрыл `ProgressBar`. Если бы вы были правы, то черный фон находился бы **под** `ProgressBar`. Вероятно, вы не поняли, что я имел ввиду.